# Irregularly shaped Modal View on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to display an irregularly shaped Modal view using `presentModalViewController`? The modal is covering the screen partially (presentation style is set to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`)

I tried simply setting the superview `clipsToBounds` to NO, it didn't work. I can't seem to get rid of the rounded corner as well.

PS: I am trying to avoid having to create a custom view and do this manually.

PPS: I noticed from the docs that we are supposed to use `presentViewController` now in iOS 5. It didn't accomplish anything different though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sort of got it working. It's a bit of a hack, but it works.

The code (this is inside the controller who spawn the modal):

```
// Present the modal
[self presentViewController:modalVC animated:YES completion:NULL];

// Let content overflow and shrink superview to a small dimension
modalVC.view.clipsToBounds = NO;
modalVC.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(modalVC.view.superview.bounds.origin.x, modalVC.view.superview.bounds.origin.y, 100, 100);
```

Now just make the modal's views bigger than the superview and you can go crazy with the shape.

Note that touches will only register on the superview area.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, you have to stick with the styles apple provide you, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

As you say, you have to build your own view and animate it.